# For each with sql reader

Tags: vb.net

I have a report that generate and excel sheet every 5min with colums like Departement ID(DeptID) and sold articales(qtysoldtoday). I want my VB application to open this excel file and read through every departement ID, select the top seller and bind it to DataGridViewer. here is a simple version of my excel sheet,

DeptID              Articles        Qty

01                   banana           2

```
                   apple              3
```

02                   orange           4

```
                   apple              5
```

Here is my code that doesn't work

```
WithEvents bsData1 As New BindingSource
Private FileName1 As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "C:\WIN\SA022.xls")
Private SheetName1 As String = "Data"
Private ConnectionNoHeader1 As String = "provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source='{0}';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=yes;"""


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Dept(0 To 2) As String
    Dept(0) = "01"
    Dept(1) = "02"
     Dim DeptNum As String


Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = String.Format(ConnectionNoHeader1, FileName1)}
        cn.Open()
        For Each DeptNum In Dept
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
                <Text>
                SELECT 
                    DeptID,
                         Article,
                              QTYSOLDTHISDAY


                FROM [<%= SheetName1 %>$]


WHERE DeptID = DeptNum and QTYSOLDTHISDAY=(select max(QTYSOLDTHISDAY) from [<%= 

SheetName1 %>$] where DeptID =  DeptNum )
</Text`>.Value,
                        cn
                )
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                dt.AcceptChanges()
                bsData1.DataSource = dt
                DataGridView2.DataSource = bsData1
            Next DeptNum
        End Using
    End Sub
```

PROBLEM AS STATED BY OP IN COMMENT BELOW:

I got nothing in gridview with for next loop. it works if I just enter the department ID in select statement, but I can't be doing that for every deprtment ID, thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? The data retrieved from the spreadsheet isn't correct? The grid binding doesn't work? You have to be more specific.

Comment: I got nothing in gridview with for next loop. it works if I just enter the department ID in select statement, but I can't be doing that for every deprtment ID, thanks

Comment: I do get data if I put WHERE DeptID = 01 in select statement but nothing if I go through the array DeptNum with the FOR NEXT

Comment: There is something odd with your code in that you actually change the `DataSource` on each iteration. If I am not mistaken, in this case you would never get the results for DeptID 01 with this code.

Comment: No this code works perfectly if I just query the excel sheet with 1 departement ID. my problem is that I have about 24 department IDs and it will be a nightmare if I have to run the same code for each of the. so I thought about the for next loop but it doesn't give anything.